# How to add margin on top of image

Tags: html, css

I have one logo (Viber app logo) going slightly on top side on the header: https://xxxxxxxx.com

See screenshot:

[image]

How can I align the Viber app logo in blue slightly lower? Like add a margin of 1 or 2 pixels from top.

Comment: Please see the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552), to which the answer is No.

Comment: Do you mean to to this ```img {
  margin-top: 2px;
}```

Comment: @PraveenDass is right !

Comment: link looks fine.  what's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `display: inline-block` and `margin-top: 2px` to the `<a>` element that contains the `<img>`.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions. You are making the site worse.

Comment: @HereticMonkey but solved his problem. aren't we here for that?

Comment: @Ruzgar No. Stack Overflow is not about helping one person at a time. It's about helping everyone with the same question. By answering this one question, hev1 has helped 1 person. If they had waited until the OP actually included the code they were using and explained the problem they were having, the answer might have helped many more people.

Comment: @HereticMonkey sometimes I wonder if I am on earth or on a enemy alien planet, my website is built using Elementor and several plugins. There is "NO Code" to show. So, sometimes don't assume that you are always right.

Comment: @ComputerUser If there is no code, how did you incorporate the code from this answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can easly add `position: relative` and then add `top: 2px`. Then element will position itself based on itself.

Comment: np :) The real question is why you can't use margin-top: 2px ?

Comment: because the website is built using Elementor and like 20-25 plugins with it, and when I tried margin-top, it doesn't work. And I don't have time to find the reason for it.

Comment: Ok, I was just curious